# Redownload file only if file is different android

Tags: android, download, md5, md5sum

need a logic to download file when i run my android app from same link for example

www.example.com/folders/examplefile.doc

in my splash activity I download examplefile.doc only on the first launch of the application

but i want a efficient way of check if examplefile.doc is updated without downloaded examplefile.doc again and comparing md5 values.

must be efficient because i must do this for a large amount of files

Is there some way i could check if the file is the same one that i have previously downloaded and only download if the file is a newer version.

Comment: Do you control the server that serves the files?

Comment: technically i do i can get access to it but would prefer a method without it but sure lets say i do what could i use in that case

Comment: Implement a polling system to check if any files have been modified. There's really no way to do that without adding something to your server.

Comment: any guides to push me into the direction of how to do this on my web server